# How can I change lesspipe's color scheme?

Tags: terminal, colors, less, syntax-highlighting

When I `less /some/file.ext`, I get syntax highlighting by `/usr/bin/lesspipe`. Unfortunately, the colors are annoying and have poor visibility on my distro, by default - it's Devuan 3.0.

My question: How can I view, edit or replace/choose the color scheme used by lesspipe?

Bonus points if you can tell me how to make it follow my `vim`'s color scheme.

**edit:**

It seems the color is done by the [`source-highlight`](https://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight.html) library.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to define it in [code2color](https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/~friebel/unix/less/code2color).  The documentation [here](https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/~friebel/unix/lesspipe.html) lists the background.

> Syntax highlighting of source code is possible through an included
>   script code2color which is derived from Peter Palfraders code2html
>   script or an external program (pygmentize). The script code2color is
>   written in perl and has colorizing support for the languages ada, asm,
>   awk, c, c++, groff, html, xml, java, javascript, lisp, m4, make,
>   pascal, patch, perl, povray, python, ruby, shellscript and sql.
>
> Syntax highlighting and other methods of colorizing the output are
>   only activated if the environment variable LESS is existing and
>   contains the option -R or -r or less is called with one of these
>   options. This guarantees, that instead of literal escape sequences
>   colors are displayed. The detection of the -r/-R presence at runtime
>   is rather dependent on the operating system and may not work in all
>   cases.
>
> The script lesspipe.sh needs a lot of helper programs that may or may
>   not be installed on your computer. Therefore you should download the
>   tarball lesspipe.tar.gz and use configure to customize lesspipe.sh for
>   the local computer. A preconfigured lesspipe.sh for Linux is provided
>   as an example only. There syntax highlighting is switched on. The
>   code2color script does the colorization, but can be replaced by an
>   external program (pygmentize)
>
> To get support for newer file types an additional magic file (for use
>   in the file command, e.g. in ~/.magic) might have to be created. In
>   that case the environment variable MAGIC has to be set and has to
>   contain both the system magic file and your personal one. Example:
>   MAGIC='/usr/share/file/magic:/Users/myaccount/.magic' export MAGIC

Comment: It doesn't look like code2color is installed on my system.

Comment: I found Wolfgang Friebel's GitHub here https://github.com/wofr06/lesspipe.  You could use that to download code2color.